# Reset Excel StatusBar with AppleScript on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, excel-2011

I can't reset the Excel StatusBar from AppleScript (Excel for Mac 2011 on Mavericks).

Setting a value works:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set status bar to "Test"
end tell
```

But resetting it writes `false`instead of `Ready`into the StatusBar:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set status bar to false
end tell
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just trying to remove your text? If so, you should be able to just do this..

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set status bar to ""
end tell
```

Comment: This would be a workaround. But the default StatusBar prints "Ready", not an empty string.

Comment: The only commands available for the status bar that i see are "display status bar" and "status bar". So I don't think I would consider set status bar to "Ready" a workaround but rather the intended practice. Better yet would be probably something like this... set cStatus to get status bar then do your script to change the status and when you're finished, reset it using set status bar to cStatus

Comment: Just try `get status bar`and it'll return `false`. But setting it to `false`doesn't work. That's the only problem. According to the Excel 2004 AppleScript guide it should work, and in VBA, it works, too: `Application.StatusBar = False`

Comment: I did what you said with the **get status bar** and saw the value of false returned. So then I tried setting a value and resetting it with my example of **set status bar to ""**, after that, when I did the **get status bar**, it also returns **false**